# Magento CLI Setup, invalid entity type specified: catalog_category

Tags: kubernetes, magento2, minikube

I try to install Magento 2 via CLI (inside a Minikube). I set all the required parameters, but it often happens that the setup fails with the error message beyond. I can run the setup command again, and it completes without an error. As this setup process should be fully automated and failsafe, I have to find out, what's wrong here.

```
Upgrading data... 
[Progress: 466 / 905]
Module 'Magento_Cms':
[Progress: 467 / 905]
Module 'Magento_Catalog':

In PatchApplier.php line 167:

  Invalid entity_type specified: catalog_category

setup:install [--backend-frontname BACKEND-FRONTNAME] [--enable-debug-logging ENABLE-DEBUG-LOGGING] [--enable-syslog-logging ENABLE-SYSLOG-LOGGING] [--amqp-host AMQP-HOST] [--amqp-port AMQP-PORT] [--amqp-user AMQP-USER] [--amqp-password AMQP-PASSWORD] [--amqp-virtualhost AMQP-VIRTUALHOST] [--amqp-ssl AMQP-SSL] [--amqp-ssl-options AMQP-SSL-OPTIONS] [--key KEY] [--db-host DB-HOST] [--db-name DB-NAME] [--db-user DB-USER] [--db-engine DB-ENGINE] [--db-password DB-PASSWORD] [--db-prefix DB-PREFIX] [--db-model DB-MODEL] [--db-init-statements DB-INIT-STATEMENTS] [-s|--skip-db-validation] [--http-cache-hosts HTTP-CACHE-HOSTS] [--session-save SESSION-SAVE] [--session-save-redis-host SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-HOST] [--session-save-redis-port SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-PORT] [--session-save-redis-password SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-PASSWORD] [--session-save-redis-timeout SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-TIMEOUT] [--session-save-redis-persistent-id SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-PERSISTENT-ID] [--session-save-redis-db SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-DB] [--session-save-redis-compression-threshold SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-COMPRESSION-THRESHOLD] [--session-save-redis-compression-lib SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-COMPRESSION-LIB] [--session-save-redis-log-level SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-LOG-LEVEL] [--session-save-redis-max-concurrency SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-MAX-CONCURRENCY] [--session-save-redis-break-after-frontend SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-BREAK-AFTER-FRONTEND] [--session-save-redis-break-after-adminhtml SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-BREAK-AFTER-ADMINHTML] [--session-save-redis-first-lifetime SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-FIRST-LIFETIME] [--session-save-redis-bot-first-lifetime SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-BOT-FIRST-LIFETIME] [--session-save-redis-bot-lifetime SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-BOT-LIFETIME] [--session-save-redis-disable-locking SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-DISABLE-LOCKING] [--session-save-redis-min-lifetime SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-MIN-LIFETIME] [--session-save-redis-max-lifetime SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-MAX-LIFETIME] [--session-save-redis-sentinel-master SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-SENTINEL-MASTER] [--session-save-redis-sentinel-servers SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-SENTINEL-SERVERS] [--session-save-redis-sentinel-verify-master SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-SENTINEL-VERIFY-MASTER] [--session-save-redis-sentinel-connect-retires SESSION-SAVE-REDIS-SENTINEL-CONNECT-RETIRES] [--cache-backend CACHE-BACKEND] [--cache-backend-redis-server CACHE-BACKEND-REDIS-SERVER] [--cache-backend-redis-db CACHE-BACKEND-REDIS-DB] [--cache-backend-redis-port CACHE-BACKEND-REDIS-PORT] [--cache-backend-redis-password CACHE-BACKEND-REDIS-PASSWORD] [--cache-id-prefix CACHE-ID-PREFIX] [--page-cache PAGE-CACHE] [--page-cache-redis-server PAGE-CACHE-REDIS-SERVER] [--page-cache-redis-db PAGE-CACHE-REDIS-DB] [--page-cache-redis-port PAGE-CACHE-REDIS-PORT] [--page-cache-redis-compress-data PAGE-CACHE-REDIS-COMPRESS-DATA] [--page-cache-redis-password PAGE-CACHE-REDIS-PASSWORD] [--page-cache-id-prefix PAGE-CACHE-ID-PREFIX] [--base-url BASE-URL] [--language LANGUAGE] [--timezone TIMEZONE] [--currency CURRENCY] [--use-rewrites USE-REWRITES] [--use-secure USE-SECURE] [--base-url-secure BASE-URL-SECURE] [--use-secure-admin USE-SECURE-ADMIN] [--admin-use-security-key ADMIN-USE-SECURITY-KEY] [--admin-user [ADMIN-USER]] [--admin-password [ADMIN-PASSWORD]] [--admin-email [ADMIN-EMAIL]] [--admin-firstname [ADMIN-FIRSTNAME]] [--admin-lastname [ADMIN-LASTNAME]] [--cleanup-database] [--sales-order-increment-prefix SALES-ORDER-INCREMENT-PREFIX] [--use-sample-data] [--enable-modules [ENABLE-MODULES]] [--disable-modules [DISABLE-MODULES]] [--convert-old-scripts [CONVERT-OLD-SCRIPTS]] [-i|--interactive] [--safe-mode [SAFE-MODE]] [--data-restore [DATA-RESTORE]] [--dry-run [DRY-RUN]] [--magento-init-params MAGENTO-INIT-PARAMS]
```

Comment: Can you post `Deployment` for the Magento container, or which guide have you used?

Answer (score 5):

I figured out, that my php had not enough memory. I set the memory of my memory to 4GB and it finally worked for me.

Comment: this helped me!